# How to check WSO2 CEP is correctly configured with Apache storm for distributed processing

Tags: wso2, apache-storm, wso2-cep

I am using latest WSO2 CEP (v4.1.0), and apache storm 0.9.6 for WSO2 CEP clustering in distributed manner ([distributed mode deployment](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+CEP+4.1.0#ClusteringCEP4.1.0-DistributedmodedeploymentDistributedCEP)). I have followed the [guidelines](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+CEP+4.1.0) which was provided by WSO2 for CEP clustering.

After following those guidelines CEP is working properly. Now I want to make sure CEP is correctly clusterd or not.Is there any mechanism to check whether it is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried one of the [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Sample+0504+-+Processing+a+Distributed+Siddhi+Query+with+Partitioning+by+integrating+with+Apache+Storm) which was provided by WSO2. Then Storm UI will show spouts and bolts which are created according to the given Siddhi query. Using that we can decide CEP is correctly clustered or not.

Apche storm UI shows the bolts and spouts in following manner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see similar logs like following. You can notice the IP and clustering port of other members in the log.

```
INFO - MemberUtils Added member: Host:192.168.1.100, Remote Host:null, Port: 4200, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
INFO - HazelcastClusteringAgent Hazelcast initialized in 1283ms
INFO - HazelcastClusteringAgent Local member: [03fa03f7-176b-48d5-9173-48866d7dd641] - Host:192.168.1.100, Remote Host:null, Port: 4100, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2con.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true
INFO - HazelcastClusteringAgent Elected this member [03fa03f7-176b-48d5-9173-48866d7dd641] as the Coordinator node

[2015-09-14 11:31:44,162]  INFO - WKABasedMembershipScheme Member joined [a0f1c3cd-adaf-4fdf-ac9f-d6c6f3508022]: /192.168.1.100:4300
[2015-09-14 11:31:46,230]  INFO - MemberUtils Added member: Host:192.168.1.100, Remote Host:null, Port: 4300, HTTP:8282, HTTPS:8245, Domain: wso2con.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
```